# WebBrowser, check if button is available

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to click a button on a webpage.
I've got the current code:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("load-more").InvokeMember("click")
```

However, I've got other code to scroll down on the page as the whole page doesn't load until you reach the bottom.
Eventually, after you reach the bottom a few times you've got a choice if you want to load more things.
The ID of that button you click to load more is "load-more", however, that button isn't always available.

So how is it possible that it waits until the button is clickable until it actually clicks the button?

I've tried using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6500)` but I can't use that because if I do the page won't automatically scroll down.

Anyone got any ideas on how I can achieve this?

I've focused on the WebBrowser:

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Body.Focus()
```

and the I sent keys to WebBrowser to scroll:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{END 5}")
```

The scroll script now looks like this:

```
Dim Wait As Date
Now.AddSeconds(Second)
Wait = Now.AddSeconds(Second).AddSeconds(1)

Do Until Now > Wait
    Application.DoEvents() ' Allow windows messages to be processed
Loop
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Body.Focus()
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{END 5}")
```

So basically, now, once the webpage has been loaded it automatically scrolls down to the bottom.

I still have no clue how to check if a button is clickable - the button only appears once the webpage has been scrolled to the bottom a few times (more content loads with every scroll).

Comment: What if your page takes 6.6 seconds to load?

Comment: What is the code that scroll your page down?

Comment: The page auto scrolls after the page has loaded.

Comment: Added the code to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out how to do this.
It's actually really easy!
First off, I've got this code:

```
Const Second As Double = 1.0# / (1440.0# * 60.0#)
    Dim Wait As Date
    Now.AddSeconds(Second)
    Wait = Now.AddSeconds(Second).AddSeconds(1)
    Do Until Now > Wait
        Application.DoEvents() ' Allow windows messages to be processed
    Loop
    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Body.Focus()
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{END 5}")
```

It basically waits a little and the sends the "END" key 5 times consecutively, the "END" key just scrolls to the end of the page.

I've then got this code:

```
Dim buttonAv = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("load-more")
    If buttonAv <> Nothing Then
        buttonAv.ScrollIntoView(True)
        WebBrowser1.Document.All("load-more").InvokeMember("click")
    End If
```

Basically, I'm making the button I want to click (the ID for it is "load-more") as 'buttonAv', then I check if buttonAv is in view - if it isn't I scroll it into view and then click it.